# How to declare getters/setters for an array member variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm trying to represent a Course with Students. The Students have information about their first and last names, age... And the Courses have a name and an array of 3 Students.

I'm getting an error when I try to define the getters and setters for the array.

> Error (active) E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from "Student [3]" to "Student"
>
> Error (active) E0137   expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Course.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Student.h"
#include "Teacher.h"


class Course
{
private:
    string name;
    Student students[3];
    Teacher teacher;

public:
    Course();
    ~Course();
    void setName(string name);
    string getName();
    void setStudents(Student students[3]);
    [3] Student getStudents();
};
```

Course.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Course.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Teacher.h"
using namespace std;

Course::Course() {}

Course::~Course()
{
}

void Course::setName(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

string Course::getName()
{
    return this->name;
}

void Course::setStudents(Student students[3])
{
    /*for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this->students[i] = students[i];
    }*/ 
     //This way the set works
    this->students = students;
}

[3]Student Course::getStudents()
{
    return this->students;
}
```

I expect the output of the get to be the array of students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C style array cannot be copied, cannot be automatically assigned, and cannot be returned from a function.

Thankfully, the C++ standard library provides a thin wrapper class over C style arrays which implement all these operations. It’s called `std::array` and it can be used exactly like you’re trying to use C-style arrays.

```
#pragma once
#include "Student.h"
#include "Teacher.h"
#include <array>

class Course
{
   private:
    string name;
    std::array<Student, 3> students;
    Teacher teacher;

   public:
    Course();
    ~Course();
    void setName(string name);
    string getName();
    void setStudents(std::array<Student, 3> students);
    std::array<Student, 3> getStudents();
};
```